# SQL Server : group by with corresponding row values

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I need to write a T-SQL group by query for a table with multiple dates and seq columns:

```
DROP TABLE #temp
CREATE TABLE #temp(
       id char(1),
       dt DateTime,
       seq int)

Insert into #temp values('A','2015-03-31 10:00:00',1)
Insert into #temp values('A','2015-08-31 10:00:00',2)
Insert into #temp values('A','2015-03-31 10:00:00',5)
Insert into #temp values('B','2015-09-01 10:00:00',1)
Insert into #temp values('B','2015-09-01 10:00:00',2)
```

I want the results to contains only the items A,B with their *latest date* and the *corresponding* seq number, like:

```
id  MaxDate CorrespondentSeq
A   2015-08-31 10:00:00.000 2
B   2015-09-01 10:00:00.000 2
```

I am trying with (the obviously wrong!):

```
select id, max(dt) as MaxDate, max(seq) as CorrespondentSeq
from #temp
group by id
```

which returns:

```
id  MaxDate CorrespondentSeq
A   2015-08-31 10:00:00.000 5  <-- 5 is wrong
B   2015-09-01 10:00:00.000 2
```

How can I achieve that?

**EDIT**

The `dt datetime` column has duplicated values (exactly same date!)

I am using SQL Server 2005

Comment: If there are rows with Duplicate dates for the same id, then you need to specify what the query processor should use to determine which of the duplicates to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ranking subselect to get only the highest ranked entries for an id:

```
select id, dt, seq 
from (
        select id, dt, seq, rank() over (partition by id order by dt desc, seq desc) as r
        from #temp            
     ) ranked
where r=1;
```

Comment: I like very much this solution as I think is the mostly explicative... First it order the table by dt, seq partitioning it by id... and then select the rows with `rank 1`... smart!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, DT, SEQ 
FROM (
        SELECT ID, DT, SEQ, Row_Number()
            OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt DESC, seq DESC) AS row_number
        FROM temp            
     ) cte
WHERE row_number = 1;
```

Demo : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3e3d5/5

Answer (score 0):

```
Select id, dt, seq
From #temp t
where dt = (Select Max(dt) from #temp
            Where id = t.Id)
```

If there are duplicate rows, then you also need to specify what the query processor should use to determine which of the duplicates to return. Say you want the lowest value of `seq`,

Then you could write:

```
Select id, dt, seq
From #temp t
where dt = (Select Max(dt) from #temp
            Where id = t.Id)
   and seq = (Select Min(Seq) from #temp
              where id = t.Id
                 and dt = t.dt)
```

Comment: In case of equals Dates, this returns:

id dt seq

B 2015-09-01 10:00:00.000 1

B 2015-09-01 10:00:00.000 2

A 2015-08-31 10:00:00.000 2

(Returns both the B row!)

Answer (score 0):

With trial and errors maybe I have found a solution, but I'm not completely sure this is correct:

```
select A.id, B.dt, max(B.seq) 
from (select id, max(dt) as maxDt
      from #temp
      group by id) as A
inner join #temp as B on A.id = B.id AND A.maxDt = B.dt
group by A.id, B.dt
```